# angular.json-> Property buildTarget is not allowed

Tags: angular, angular17, angular.json

I have migrated to Angular 17 using the migration tool. Everything works fine. But my angular.json shows a warning "Property buildTarget is not allowed."

Before, `browserTarget` was there, but the migration tool replaced it with `buildTarget`. When I use `browserTarget`, I'm getting an error that it is deprecated.

Here is my `angular.json` file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "testAng": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "standalone": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "standalone": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "standalone": false
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/test-ang",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "testAng:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "testAng:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "testAng:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How to solve the problem with "Property buildTarget is not allowed"?

I am using

- Angular: 17.1.1
- Angular CLI: 17.1.1
- Node: 20.11.0

Comment: Try using `target` instead of `buildTarget`.

Comment: In my projects the `angular.json` looks pretty much the same and it works properly for me. Where exactly do you see this warning "Property buildTarget is not allowed"? Is it displayed when running some command, and if yes which? Or is it just displayed by the IDE? If it's displayed just by the IDE, which one are you using in which version? It's possible that it's a bug in the IDE.

Comment: I am using VS Code, Its showing in IDE only.   for even `target` also showing warning.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. I'm in the process of upgrading to Angular 17, and noticed in my angular.json file that both `buildTarget` and `target` are highlighted in VSCode as deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command: yarn add @angular-devkit/build-webpack

The warning "Property buildTarget is not allowed" in the angular.json file might be related to missing or outdated dependencies in your Angular project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while migrating to angular v17.

As simple as it sounds,

### Solution

**closing VsCode** and reopening it fixed the issue.

### Versions

Angular: `17.3.2`
Angular CLI: `17.3.2`
Node: `20.11.0`
Package Manager: `npm 10.2.4`